# Is std::map creating a new non const copy of object from its const reference

Tags: c++, memory, reference, stdmap

Consider the following code .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A{

public:
    int m_id;
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    A() = default;
    A(int i, int j, int k) : m_id(i), m_x(j), m_y(k){}
};

void add(const A& a, std::map<int,A>& m){
    m[a.m_id] = a; 
}

void modify(std::map<int,A>& m){
    for(auto& x : m){
        x.second.m_x*=10;
        x.second.m_y/=10;
    }
}
void print(std::map<int,A>& m){
    for(const auto& x : m){
        std::cout << x.first << " : (" << x.second.m_x << ',' << x.second.m_y << ")\n";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    std::map<int,A> m;
    A a(1,10,100);
    add(a,m);
    print(m);
    {
        A b(2,10,200);
        add(b,m);
        print(m);
    }    

    modify(m);
    print(m);
    return 0;
}
```

I am creating a `std::map` of objects of type `A`. In `add`, I add an object to the `std::map` by using a `const` reference to that object. In `modify`, I am modifying values of `std::map`. In `print`, I am printing the map. Basically accessing the elements.
I add `b` in a different scope to test if it I get a memory error.
The code works correctly.
My question is, is `std::map` with `[]` operator creating a new non `const` copy of the object ? Also, `std::vector::push_back` works fine. Does `push_back` also create a copy. I am not calling `emplace`.

Comment: void print(const std::map<int,A>& m) print doesn't modify the map

Comment: Because your map type is a value type every add creates a copy of that object. You only would have the same object if you use a reference or pointer

Comment: std::vector<T,Allocator>::push_back creates a copy when you pass a l-value and moves when you pass a r-value

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Yup. I am modifying map in `modify`, In print I am accessing elements to check if I get any memory error after b goes out of scope.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at operator[] add a default constructed object if the key is not present than you use assignment. use insert instead, that will use copy constructor

Comment: Look at this code example to use a reference in a map: https://godbolt.org/z/rzvrcoGo4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a new object will be constructed as the element of `std::map`. To be precise, in `m[a.m_id] = a;`, if the key (i.e. `a.m_id`) does not already exist, a value-initialized `A` will be constructed as the new element of `m` firstly, then `m[a.m_id]` returns the reference to value of the new element; which is copy-assigned from `a` via the copy-assignment operator of `A` later.

If the key (i.e. `a.m_id`) already exists, `m[a.m_id]` just returns the reference to value of the existed element; which is copy-assigned from `a` then.

Comment: The "new element" part assumes that `a.m_id` is a new key. If not, the existing element with the same key will be replaced. There's also `std::map::insert` which will fail if there is an existing element, and `std::map::insert_or_assign` which is a more efficient form skipping the value initialization.